# How do I add a newline in PL/SQL after each group of data?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So, let's say I have something like this:

```
select first_name, last_name, account_number
from accounts
having count(distinct account_number) > 2;
```

Let's day it produces the following results:

```
John, Doe, 12345
Mary, Smith, 12345
Joe, Foo, 30000
Foo, Yung, 30000
Larry, Leisure, 30000
```

What I'd like to do is have a newline between each set of grouped data to distinguish between each group and make it more readable.  In this case, I'd like a newline between the "12345" and the "30000" account numbers.  Any ideas on how to do that?  I've played with using chr, but can't seem to get anything to work.

P.S.  Using SQL*Developer at the moment.

Thanks!!

Comment: Your query is incorrect. Please correct it with `group by` section and add samples of input and output data

Comment: The rows that you want to add as newlines they are fixed or changeble?

Comment: In SQL*Plus that would be [`break`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve009.htm). Perhaps SQL Developer emulates this. Why, though?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
    tablea
    AS
        (SELECT 'John' FIRST, 'Doe' LAST, 12345 account_number
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Mary', 'Smith', 12345
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Joe', 'Foo', 30000
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Foo', 'Yung', 30000
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Larry', 'Leisure', 30000
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT account_number
     , FIRST
     ,    LAST
       || CASE
              WHEN lead (account_number)
                       OVER (
                           PARTITION BY account_number ORDER BY last
                       )
                       IS NULL
              THEN
                  CHR (13) || CHR (10)
              ELSE
                  NULL
          END as last

  FROM tablea
  order by account_number, last
```